# J-Unit JavaFX Tookit not Initialized

Tags: javafx, junit5

I wrote a few J-unit tests for a class I use in my JavaFX project. I am however, running into a "Tookit not initialized" again and again. I'm new to JavaFX and J-Unit testing, so I'm not sure where to look.

I edited the VM options from -ea to "--module-path C:\Users\myName\Desktop\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml" in order to fix a No suitable pipeline found error.

This is my test class code:

```
package HHS_PROJ1.models;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class AnimalTest {
private Animal animal;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    animal = new Animal(5, "Goat", 32, 10, 0, new Button("bid"));

}

@Test
void setHighestOffer() {
    try {
        animal.setHighestOffer(8);
        fail("Entering a lower offer than current highestOffer should throw an exception");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("Caught lower offer than current highest in setHighestOffer(): " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail("Wrong exception thrown for entering a lower offer than the current highestOffer");
    }
}

@Test
void setAmount() {
    try {
        animal.setAmount(-2);
        fail("Entering a negative number should throw an exception");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("Caught negative number in setAmount(): " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail("Wrong exception thrown for entering a negative number");
    }
}
}
```

I would like to be able to run my tests, to see if my code works as intended.

Comment: you have to start up the fx application thread manually and then run each test method on the fx thread, see f.i. http://andrewtill.blogspot.com/2012/10/junit-rule-for-javafx-controller-testing.html

Comment: @kleopatra fixed it in a different way, see my answer if you're interested or not. Thanks for answering anyway

Comment: Your imports indicate you have both JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 on the classpath/modulepath. You should only use one or the other, preferably JUnit 5 (i.e. JUnit Jupiter). Also, you may want to look into [TestFX](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by creating a private JFXPanel, then adding the following bits to VM options "javafx.web,javafx.media,javafx.swing"

Comment: Yeah, that part is basically the same as what Andrew does in his blog and solving the toolkit-not-initialized. Additionally, you have to make sure that the test methods actually run on the fx thread